# Regex.Replace for IP address

Tags: regex, replace, ip

I've lifted a piece of code from somewhere on the internet it looks like this

```
 ip = Regex.Replace(ip, @"^(?<Prefix>(\d{1,3}\.){3})\d{1,3}$", "${Prefix}*");
```

What it does is takes an IP address and replaces the last section with a asterisk. For example `192.168.0.1` would become `192.168.0.*`

I'm useless with RegEx, I've tried to understand what the above is actually doing, but not having any success.

What I'm after is 2 more `Regex.Replace` code so that `192.168.0.1` becomes

- `192.168.*.*`
- `192.*.*.*`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Whoa, the editor messed things up, I think.  However, it illustrates a point that you don't need to escape those characters if they are inside backticks or code blocks. EDIT: It seems to have been fixed by a later editor.

Comment: to me this is so much easier to do with finding the last index of a period and substring.  or the 2nd to last period and substring.

Comment: So you want to turn 192.168.0.1 into 3 different strings each with 1,2 and 3 starred out segments from the end? Also, what language are you trying to achieve this in? C?

Comment: should `\d[1,3]` be `\d{1,3}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

192.168.*.* = `ip = Regex.Replace(ip, @"^(?<Prefix>(\d{1,3}\.){2})\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$", "${Prefix}*.*");`

192.*.*.* = `ip = Regex.Replace(ip, @"^(?<Prefix>(\d{1,3}\.))\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$", "${Prefix}*.*.*");`

Give that a shot, see what happens.

Comment: Thanks John,       I had a little problem with the above, but I think it could have been done by editing or escaping characters from the original question.        Regex.Replace(ip, @"^(?<Prefix>(\d{1,3}\.){2})\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$", "${Prefix}*.*")      Regex.Replace(ip, @"^(?<Prefix>(\d{1,3}\.))\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$", "${Prefix}*.*.*")